# How can one share internet between two computers? (18.04.5 LTS)

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

In short I have a laptop connected to the internet via wifi, I want to bridge the connections between my laptop and pc using an Ethernet cable.

I have done this before but with recent updates, the setting in IPV4 the ability to share internet via Ethernet is gone. I was wondering if there is something I can do to restore that setting.

Most importantly know how to share Internet between computers only using an Ethernet cable, taking into account that one of them is already connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simpler solution is better. While I can appreciate the wonder of IP routing or proxying through your laptop, I would buy a cheap wifi adapter for your PC, or get a really long Ethernet cable instead. Would save a lot of headache.